# Php file upload is not working

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to upload some images to server. But when i submit the form it will not write the file in the directory. I don't know how to get the exception in php(I'm new to php).

code :

```
$target = "assets/images/";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['file1']['name']);
//Writes the file to the server
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'], $target))
{
  $uploadRes=true;
  echo "sucess";
}
else {
  $uploadRes=false;
  echo "failed";
}
```

**Edit:**

Html :

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" id="addpost" method="GET" action="" name="newpost">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="form-field">Post Title</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="form-field" placeholder="Post Title" name="Post_title" value="" />
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="control-group">
         <label class="control-label" for="form-field-11">Content Here</label>
            <div class="controls">
            <textarea name="post_content"  value="" class="autosize-transition span12" id="form-field-11" style="overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; resize: horizontal; height: 67px;"></textarea>
            </div>
           </div><!-- Insert Image Code -->
           <div class="control-group">
            <div class="widget-main">
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="ace-file-input">
                        <input id="id-input-file-2" type="file" name="file1">
                        <a class="remove" href="#"></a>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="controls">
                    <div class="ace-file-input ace-file-multiple">
                    <input id="id-input-file-3" type="file" multiple="" name="file2">
                        <a class="remove" href="#">
                        <i class="icon-remove"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <label>
                    <input id="id-file-format" type="checkbox" name="file-format">
                        <span class="lbl"> Allow only images</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
              </div>
             </div><!-- Insert Image Code -->
            <div class="space-4"></div>
            <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="form-field-tags">Tag input</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input id="form-field-tags" type="hidden" placeholder="Enter tags ..." value="Tag Input Control" name="tags">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="space-4"></div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="form-field-select-3">Select Category</label>
                <div class="controls">
                <label for="form-field-select-3">Chosen</label>
                <select class="chzn-select" id="form-field-select-3" data-placeholder="Choose a Category..." name="category">
                <option value="">
                </option><option value="Blog">Blog
                </option><option value="News Letter">News Letter
                </option></select>
             </div>
           </div>

     <div class="control-group" style="float:left; margin-right:25px">
        <div class="controls"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">
        <i class="icon-ok bigger-110"></i>
        <input type="submit" value="" id="posubmit" style="opacity:0"/>Submit</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn"><i class="icon-undo bigger-110"></i>Reset</button>
        </div>
     </div> 
     <div id="resp" style="float:left; margin-top:5px">
        <img id="loading" style="visibility:hidden;" src="assets/img/ajax-load.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="loading" />
      </div>
     </form>
```

I'm submitting the form with ajax..
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the html.?

Comment: Does the `directory` have `write` permission??

Comment: have u tried to debug it??

Comment: So you upload something to your directory through php? You can also upload it in the server. I asked a question like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359101/file-upload-in-php-in-mysql

I used this:

http://bytes.com/topic/php/insights/740327-uploading-files-into-mysql-database-using-php

Just a comment. This shouldn't solve your problem but still just wanted to let you know. Maybe it is a solution cause you can choose a directory to save it in.

Comment: You have a random `0` knocking about also, after `$uploadRes=false;`.

Comment: I doubt "assets/images/" is an absolute path to where you want the images to be stored.

Comment: @ Ajith S directory have write permission

Comment: @ BeatAlex That was the mistake happened while pasting the code. Sorry about that...

Comment: You have to also use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` inside your `<form>` tag

Answer (score 1):

your form tag in html should be like the following :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="addpost" method="GET" action="" name="newpost" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```