# Uploading a images in MySql using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to upload an image through a contact form, to get a server in a particular folder and its time to visualize the database. When I submit the form I get this error:

> File is an image - image/jpeg.  Notice: Undefined index: fileToUpload
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\Web\form.php on line 68  Notice: Trying to access
>   array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Web\form.php on
>   line 68 Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\Web\form.php
>   line 82

This is the code:
HTML:

```
  <div class="container-form">
     <form action="form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="image">
       Прикачете ваша снимка! (максимален размер 20МБ)<br>
       <input type="file" name="image" id="image" size="40" required="true" />
    </div>
        <div class="submit">
           <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Изпращане" id="submit" />          
        </div>
     </form>
  </div>
```

PHP:

```
// Connect to MyQSL
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "form");
$link->query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");

// Check our connection
if ($link === false)
{
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 20000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG and PNG files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Escape user inputs for security
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['name']);
$date = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['date']);
$image = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['image']);

// Insert our data
$sql = "INSERT INTO form (name, date, image) VALUES ('$name', '$date', '$image')";
// Print response from MyQSL
if (mysqli_query($link, $sql))
{
    echo "<div class='echo-complete'> <div class='echo-text'> Формата беше приета успешно. Благодарим ви.";
}
else
{
echo "<div class='echo-error'> <div class='echo-text'> ГРЕШКА: Не може да се изпълни $sql." .         
mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close our connection
mysqli_close($link);
```

Database:
image column is type BLOB

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: **Never** get your web app to login to the database as root. Root can do whatever it likes,
so on top of the SQL injection vulnerabilities
this just leaves your database an open book for hackers.
Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly.
Don't even use the root account as a shortcut during development or testing, because you need to test your account permissions as well - otherwise when you go live you might have unexpected errors relating to the user account setup.

Comment: This site will not be published publicly, I need a diploma paper.

Comment: Also check you are inserting data correctly or not? I think it should be:  `$sql = "INSERT INTO form (name, date, image) VALUES ('$name', '$date', '$target_file')";`

Comment: "This site will not be published publicly"...doesn't matter. You should get into good habits before you have to do one which _will_ be going public. Learn how to do it correctly the first time and then you won't have to re-learn it later. It's not really any more difficult to do.

Comment: Anyway `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]` is wrong, you don't have any input with `name="fileToUpload"` in your HTML. As you've referenced correctly elsewhere in your code, `name` is the correct way to reference it. `$_FILES["image"]` should be what you need (because you have `name="image"` in the HTML)

Comment: I fixed it, but the problem is not resolved, the photo is not uploaded

Comment: Sorry I updated that comment about the $_FILES - see above now

Comment: Also you need to move all references to $_FILES inside the `if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {` block, otherwise it will try to execute that code even when you first load the page. In fact pretty much the whole of the PHP in form.php which talks to the database needs to go in there.

Comment: Yes, I did it with "image", but it doesn't work. Regarding "'$target_file'", should I remove "$image"? Should I also add a new row $$target_file = mysqli_real_escape_string ($link, $ _REQUEST ['target_file']) ?

Comment: yeah that makes no sense, you don't need that line

Comment: `$image = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['image']);` is also wrong. file uploads don't got into the $_REQUEST (or $_POST) array, they go into the $_FILES array - which you've already got some code for.

Comment: There is a whole set of manual pages devoted to file uploads (https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) as well as countless examples online on other sites, including this one. You are making quite a standard feature. It should not really be a big struggle to put together some working code.

Comment: This gives a decent example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19359406/5947043

Answer (score -1):

```
    <div class="container-form">
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           <div class="image">
               <input type="file" name="image" id="image" size="40" required="true" />
           </div>
           <div class="submit">
               <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" id="submit" />          
           </div>
        </form>
    </div>

       <!--Now we will connect to the database.-->

<?php
// define file 
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $fname  = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    $fsize  = $_FILES["image"]["size"];
    $ferror = $_FILES["image"]["error"];
    $ftype  = $_FILES["image"]["type"];
    $ftmp   = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];

    // Get the extension of the file and verify if we support it
    $allowed          = array(
        "png",
        "jpeg",
        "jpg",
        "gif"
    ); //make sure it's not capital letters.
    $actual_extension = explode(".", $fname); // Get what we have after the . on the file name
    $extension        = end($actual_extension); // make sure we got the extension
    //check if the extension is supported.
    if (!in_array($extension, $allowed)) {
        echo "Sorry! We do not support this format" . "<br>";
    }

    // Now check if we have a file error, else: upload
    if ($ferror == 1) { // Check if we have an error
        echo "Something went wrong" . "<br>";
    } else {
        if ($fsize > 100000) { // check if the uploaded file matches the size we allow.
            echo "Your file is BIG" . "<br>";
        } else {
            $new_name = uniqid('', true); // we will give the uploaded file a unique id 
            $path     = "uploads/" . $new_name . "." . $extension; // Define the path and upload the file with new name+ "." + the file extension.
            if (move_uploaded_file($ftmp, $path)) {
                echo "file uploaded succesfully";
            } else {
                echo "something went wrong with the file upload";
            }
        }
    }

    $link  = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sadik");
    $query = "INSERT INTO `table` (`image`) VALUES ($new_name) ";
    mysqli_query($link, $query);
    // ...
}
?>
```

Comment: yes, he will work on it, I just gave an idea about the file upload.